As a newly hired lecturer Is it ok to ask for a collaboration of another professor?
So I am a newly hired faculty member (lecturer), and to further my research, I wanted to ask a Professor (out of my country) for a collaboration. The problem is that I don't have an idea for a research paper, I want him to supervise and guide me. (similar to the way of a Phd student and his supervisor)
Is this appropriate?
P.S. I had worked briefly with the professor in question before.

Note that "Lecturer" means vastly different things in different countries. Where are you?

How is it a collaboration if you haven't a clue what to do? What exactly are you "collaborating" on? Collaboration implies some sort of mutually beneficial arrangement where both parties have something worthwhile to bring. It sounds like you want a mentor, not a collaborator.

I would not recommend this approach, and if somebody approached me with that request, I would turn it down.
Mentoring someone (or as you put it "supervise and guide") is a fairly large responsibility.  For a person outside of your own department, it's a pretty big ask  -- my own opinion is that it's an unreasonably big ask.
That doesn't mean you can't eventually establish a collaboration with this investigator, but the nature of your question suggests to me that you're not ready for that.  At the very least, you should be able to tell your target what specific experiments or areas you'd like to collaborate on, along with what you would bring to the table in such a collaboration.
There are departments that accept the responsibility for mentoring new hires.  In my department, it takes the form of the chair assigning seasoned faculty to informally mentor young faculty, and a more formal periodic meeting as a group to workshop young faculty's grant applications as they're being written.  If you're hurting for mentorship, I recommend starting a conversation with your chair along these lines.  Perhaps such an arrangement would be beneficial in helping you develop a relationship with the external faculty member.

Finding suitable research problems can indeed be a challenging problem!
I agree with the other answers, that emailing this person is likely to be a bad idea. So what can you do instead?
One possibility is to attend a lot of conferences. But, beyond that, I'd recommend looking for workshops which assemble teams of researchers and get them to work on questions together. It's not expected that you have an idea for a research paper when you begin, and often someone will act as mentor for the team.
For example, in mathematics, the American Institute of Mathematics runs workshops of this nature, and the American Mathematical Society runs Mathematical Research Communities. There are others as well. I have been to these programs and highly recommend them.
If your research area is something other than math, or you are somewhere other than the US -- then I don't know what programs exist, but I imagine that similar opportunities may be out there, and I urge you to look for them!

Certainly if you know them and have worked with them you can ask. But I wouldn't recommend this in other cases unless you already had some project in mind.
But be aware that you can get turned down since that professor won't be able to include you as part of their official duties and won't be paid for helping you. It would be more likely to be successful if you could contribute something.
Knowing them already makes the case special, however.
